# What command do I execute to run this xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have this XML code script and it says to use command prompt to execute it but everything I try doesnt work, it has a readme file which states

> Clone the project with git or download the source zip from the github page and extract it.
>   Open the folder and run build.xml (this may require cmd to execute).
>   Wait for the build to complete and run DarkBot.jar from cmd with --help for args.

```
<project name="DarkBot" default="generate-protocols" basedir=".">
<target name="init">
    <property name="outputDir" value="bin" />
    <property name="protocolsDir" value="protocols" />
    <property name="protocolsPackage" value="org.darkstorm.darkbot.minecraftbot.protocol" />
    <property name="deployJar" value="DarkBot.jar" />
    <property name="libraryDir" value="lib" />
    <property name="tempDir" value="temp" />
    <property name="mainClass" value="org.darkstorm.darkbot.mcwrapper.Main" />
    <property name="antContribPath" value="build/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar" />
</target>

<target name="clean" depends="init">
    <delete file="${deployJar}" failonerror="false" />
    <delete dir="${outputDir}" failonerror="false" />
    <delete dir="${tempDir}" failonerror="false" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${outputDir}" />
    <javac encoding="UTF-8" destdir="${outputDir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="src/main/java" />
        <src path="src/main/resources" />
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${libraryDir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${outputDir}">
        <fileset dir="src/main/java">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="src/main/resources">
            <exclude name="**/*.java" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>

<target name="deploy" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${tempDir}" />
    <unzip dest="${tempDir}">
        <patternset>
            <exclude name="META-INF/**" />
        </patternset>
        <fileset dir="${libraryDir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </unzip>
    <copy todir="${tempDir}">
        <fileset dir="${outputDir}">
            <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    <echo message="Manifest-Version: 1.0${line.separator}Class-Path: .${line.separator}Main-Class: ${mainClass}" file="${outputDir}/manifest.txt" />
    <jar destfile="${deployJar}" basedir="${outputDir}" manifest="${outputDir}/manifest.txt" excludes="manifest.txt" />
    <jar destfile="${deployJar}" basedir="${tempDir}" includes="**/**" update="true" />
    <delete dir="${tempDir}" />
</target>

<target name="generate-protocols" depends="deploy">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${antContribPath}" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <mkdir dir="${protocolsDir}" />
    <javac encoding="UTF-8" destdir="${protocolsDir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="src/main/protocols" />
        <classpath>
            <fileset file="${deployJar}" />
            <fileset dir="${libraryDir}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
            </fileset>
        </classpath>
    </javac>
    <propertyregex property="protocolsFolder" input="src.main.protocols.${protocolsPackage}" global="true" regexp="\." replace="/" />
    <pathconvert property="files" pathsep="${line.separator}">
        <map from="${protocolsFolder}{$file.separator}" to="" />
        <dirset dir="${protocolsFolder}">
            <include name="*" />
        </dirset>
    </pathconvert>
    <propertyregex property="protocolsFolder" override="true" input="${protocolsPackage}" global="true" regexp="\." replace="/" />
    <for list="${files}" delimiter="${line.separator}" param="file">
        <sequential>
            <local name="protocolVersion" />
            <basename property="protocolVersion" file="@{file}" />
            <mkdir dir="${protocolsDir}/META-INF/services" />
            <if>
                <contains string="${protocolVersion}" substring="x" />
                <then>
                    <propertyregex property="protocolVersion" override="true" input="${protocolVersion}" regexp="v([0-9]+)" select="\1" />
                    <echo message="${protocolsPackage}.v${protocolVersion}x.Protocol${protocolVersion}X$$Provider" file="${protocolsDir}/META-INF/services/${protocolsPackage}.ProtocolProvider" />
                    <jar destfile="${protocolsDir}/v${protocolVersion}x.jar" update="false" basedir="${protocolsDir}" includes="${protocolsFolder}/v${protocolVersion}x/**/**,META-INF/**/**" />
                </then>
                <else>
                    <propertyregex property="protocolVersion" override="true" input="${protocolVersion}" regexp="v([0-9]+)" select="\1" />
                    <echo message="${protocolsPackage}.v${protocolVersion}.Protocol${protocolVersion}$$Provider" file="${protocolsDir}/META-INF/services/${protocolsPackage}.ProtocolProvider" />
                    <jar destfile="${protocolsDir}/v${protocolVersion}.jar" update="false" basedir="${protocolsDir}" includes="${protocolsFolder}/v${protocolVersion}/**/**,META-INF/**/**" />
                </else>
            </if>
            <delete dir="${protocolsDir}/META-INF" />
        </sequential>
    </for>
    <propertyregex property="protocolBase" input="${protocolsPackage}" regexp="^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+).*" select="\1" />
    <delete dir="${protocolsDir}/${protocolBase}" />
</target>
```

Comment: This looks like an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org) build script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) build file. Download Ant and run the build targets listed E.g.

```
ant deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an ant build file, [download and install an ant](http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi), try:

```
ant init deploy
```

or some other name in target tag.

[Ant manual is here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html)